# Regex to match alphanumeric -- query rows that contain numbers in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to write a regex that matches string that has *both* numeric **and** alphabets. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` -- this pattern returns numeric as well as alphabets, but I want only alphanumeric. Basically I'm using postgresql to query rows that contain numericals in it.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you want to match and not match?

Comment: Always only alpha numeric but never foreign characters or spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think multiple regex's is the easiest way:

```
where col ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*' and
      col ~ '[0-9]' and
      col ~ '[a-zA-Z]'
```

There is probably a complicated regexp that combines this all together, but this seems like the most intuitive method.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]\d)|(?:\d[a-zA-Z])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This will match a string that contains any other character also, spaces and special characters. All you're validating is that it contains #Char or Char# is contained in the column.